# Does there exist an inner product on $\mathbb R$ besides the canonical one?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $f(x,y)$ be an inner product on the $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathbb R$.

> Is it true that $f$ must be of the form $cxy$ for some nonnegative constant $c$?

Comment: $c$ has to be positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes because the conditions

- $\langle \alpha x,y\rangle=\alpha\langle x,y\rangle$
- $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$
- $\langle x,x\rangle\geq 0$

imply

- $f(x,y)=xyf(1,1)$
- $f(1,1)\geq 0$

So, $f(x,y)=cxy$ for the nonnegative constant $c=f(1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [@Pedro's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2303455/154545), we note that $f(x,y)$ is an inner product on $\Bbb R^{n}$ if and only if there exists a [positive definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) $M\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $f(x,y)=x^TMy$ for every $x,y$. In the particular case of $n=1$, we have $M\in\Bbb R$ is positive definite if and only if $M>0$, that is $f(x,y)=cxy$ with $c=M$.